# Hierarchy table, update column for a particular level

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

So I have a hierarchy table in the following format:

```
Instance | Parent | Serial | Hierarchy Level
    1    |   0    |   x0   |         1
    2    |   0    |   x1   |         1
    3    |   1    |   xy0  |         2
    4    |   1    |   xy1  |         2
    5    |   2    |    -   |         2
    6    |   2    |    -   |         2
    7    |   2    |    -   |         2
```

And what I would like to get is:

```
Instance | Parent | Serial | Hierarchy Level
    1    |   0    |   x0   |         1
    2    |   0    |   x1   |         1
    3    |   1    |   xy0  |         2
    4    |   1    |   xy1  |         2
    5    |   1    |   x0   |         2
    6    |   2    |   x1   |         2
    7    |   2    |   x1   |         2
```

All level 1's have a serial number. My goal is to update all level 2's where Serial is null, and to do this, I would have to select the parent's serial number. Could someone give me an idea of how to go about this?

This is what I've tried so far (as well as a couple of other things, to no avail):

```
UPDATE "USER"."TABLE" AS A1
SET A1.SERIAL = 
(
    SELECT "SERIAL" 
    FROM "USER"."TABLE" AS A2
    WHERE A2."PARENT" = A1."INSTANCE" 
)
WHERE "SERIAL" IS NULL
AND "HIERARCHYLEVEL" = 2
```

Native to Java, I feel like this should be a lot easier, but I am having a lot of difficulties with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your parent and instance criterion is backward in the subquery.  Also, there's redundancy, possibly leading to data discrepancy, in your data structure.  The hierarchy level should be determinable (and thus determined) by the number of parents that a row has.  By storing that value, you might be introducing a conflict: a data value that is at odds with reality.

Comment: @rd_nielsen Cheers!!! The parent and instance criterion was, in fact, backwards! Such a simple fix; upset I had to waste your time! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question. The simple fix was as @rd_nielsen explained in the OP responses:

```
UPDATE "user"."table" AS A1
SET A1.serial = 
(
    SELECT "serial" 
    FROM "user"."table" AS A2
    WHERE A1."PARENT"  = A2."INSTANCE"
)
WHERE "serial" IS NULL
AND "HIERARCHYLEVEL" = 2
```